# I can't stock my input data from a form into an array

Tags: php

I have an issue; I'm trying to send to a page all the informations the user put in a form. The form's inputs are variable, depending on what the user sets. (The form represents a test that the user can set). So here is how I'm doing my page with the form :

```
<form method="post" action="test_voc_fr.php">
    <div class="row">
<?php                   
    $questionNumber = 1; 
    $questionId = 100;

    while($return = $request->fetch()) { 

        if($return['kanji'] == NULL) {
            $return['kanji'] = "--";
        }
?>                  
        <div class="col-md-3">  
            <label for="<?php echo $questionNumber; ?>"><strong><?php echo $return['kanji']." (".$return['hiragana'].") :"; ?></strong></label> 
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $questionId; ?>" id="<?php echo $questionNumber; ?>" value="<?php echo $return['id']; ?>">
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo $questionNumber; ?>" id="<?php echo $questionNumber; ?>">
        </div>                          
<?php                       $questionNumber++;
        $questionId--;
    }

?>                  
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="number" value="<?php echo $number ?>"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Voir les résultats">    
</form>
```

And here is the other page where I treat all the input to put them in an array :

```
$number = $_POST['number']; 

$testAnswer = array();
$answerId = array();

for($n = 1; $n <= $number; $n++) {
    $testAnswer[$n] = $_POST[$n];
    echo $testAnswer[$n]."<br>";
}



for($n = 100; $n > (100-$number); $n--) {

    $increase = 1;      
    $answerId[$increase] = $_POST[$n];      
    echo $answerId[$increase]."<br>";
    $increase++;
}
```

The first array `$testAnswer[]` is good as all the information is inside. But the second array `$answerId[]` only contains one value on index `[1]`. 
Thing is, inside the `for` loop, the line `echo $answerId[$increase]` is correctly showing all the different ids. But outside the `for` loop, when I use `print_r($answerId)`, I only have one value.

I'm learning to code, and this is the first time I use stackoverflow, so sorry if there is obvious mistake here.

Comment: you shouldn't use integers on there own for IDs or Names, `$number`  isn't assigned, I assume it is meant to be `$questionNumber`

Comment: @akaBase my understanding is that `$number` is defined by the `name=` parameter in the following line from the form file: `<input type="hidden" name="number" value="<?php echo $number ?>"> `

Comment: No it doesn't work like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're logic in for loop is wrong. You are setting `$increase` always to 1, when you enter the loop again. `$increase` will always be `1`, and hence override the previous data. Set `$increase` before, outside the loop, and increase it inside.

```
$increase = 1;

for($n = 100; $n > (100-$number); $n--) {

    $answerId[$increase] = $_POST[$n];      
    echo $answerId[$increase]."<br>";
    $increase++;
}
```